# Navigation issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pop to specific class in my app.
It works fine in iOS 8 but

**Problem**
in iOS 7: it gives me error like "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted"

My code is as follow

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
            {
                if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MyAccountVC class]])
                {
                    [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];

                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: where exactly are you calling this code?

Comment: @Nishant, I calling in ViewWillDisappear Method,

I also tried with ViewDidDisappear but not working

Answer (score 0):

*Point 1:* `viewWillDisapear` is called before the view has popped from the navigation stack. Writing another `popToViewController` method inside this will cause a transition clash as both the transitions are `animated:YES`.

*Point 2:* The back button action of the `UINavigationController` can be modified by implementing the custom back button as shown in code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarbackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backToView:)]; // you can also use a custom image for back button
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = navigationBarbackButton;
}


- (IBAction)backToView:(id)sender
{
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MyAccountVC class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please update your question with code which can show how/why `viewWillDisappear` is being called.

Comment: what do you mean? it is called automatically

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is called automatically, for example, when we write the popViewController code... so what is that code or IBAction that is triggering this?

Comment: when back button of navigation pressed then viewWillDisappear called & code runs

Comment: In that case, you will have customize the back button with your own IBAction method so that it pops to the desired view controller. This code won't work with default back button or even inside in `viewWillDisappear`. I will edit my answer for this.